# Writing a query that returns the latest row related to a specific user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Trying to create a query that gets the most recent record related to the user. Here's my attempt

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    ORDER BY id
    DESC LIMIT 1)
 WHERE userid = $userID";
```

Comment: Skip the sub-query.

Comment: with this query you will get last record for all users, and then are you filtering this one record with desired user, this is the fault.

Comment: Whats wrong with your attempt? Add the error which you are getting. It would be related to table alias which you are missing on your derived table. and like @jarlh said you don't really need to use derived table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also:

```
Select * from table 
Where id =
   (Select Max(Id) from table
    where userid = $userID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply skip the sub-query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  mytable
WHERE userid = $userID
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Top(1)**

```
Select TOP(1) * FROM table  ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: `TOP` is for SQL Server. MySQL has `LIMIT`. (And ANSI SQL has `FETCH FIRST`.)

Comment: That's right, i have read title which show sql anyway you are right

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE userid = $userID
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
```